# Linewidth of 3D plot in Matlab relative to axis

Tags: matlab, properties, plot, line

I have 3D coordinates of two beams. Their coordinates are set in meters.
I also know the diameter of the beams. What I want to do is plot the linewidth of the beam to be with same units as the length.
(In my real problem I have over 40 beams)

Here is my draft.

```
clear;clc;
coordinates(:,:,1) = [1 0 1 ; 2 0 0];   % meters
coordinates(:,:,2) = [0 1 2 ; 1 0 2];   % meters

width = [0.05 , 0.09]                   % meters

[q,w,e] = size(coordinates);

for i = 1:e
    plot3(coordinates(:,1,i), coordinates(:,2,i), coordinates(:,3,i), 'LineWidth',width(i); % <- Defining different linewidth.
    hold on
end
```

If this isn't possible I would like to be able to set linewidth for each beam from a vector.

Comment: I think you're better off with `patch` for this

Comment: Thanks for point at 'patch' . I've already tried but I didn't manage to see the third dimension.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what you mean by "on the same scale as the length" haha. Do you mean longer beams should be ticker?

Comment: @Benoit_11 I think they mean the same _units_

Comment: Yes, I mean the width should have same units as the axis. But if it isn't possible I would at least want to be able to define width for each beam. (Read width from a vector) - Sorry for my English. :)